# How do I show 2 different numbers on a 2 digit 10 pin 7 segment display?

Tags: c++, arduino

```
int a = 13;
int b = 6;
int c = 11;
int d = 10;
int e = 9;
int f = 8;
int g = 7;
int digit1 = 5;
int digit2 = 4;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(c, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(e, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(f, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(digit1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(digit2, OUTPUT);

}

void six() {
  digitalWrite(a, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(c, LOW);
  digitalWrite(d, LOW);
  digitalWrite(e, LOW);
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g, LOW);
  digitalWrite(digit1, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  }

  void nine() {
  digitalWrite(a, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b, LOW);
  digitalWrite(c, LOW);
  digitalWrite(d, LOW);
  digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g, LOW);
  digitalWrite(digit2, HIGH);
    }
void loop()
{
  six();
  nine();
}
```

I have got this code in which I want to show the number 69 on my display but all it is showing is 66 Can anyone tell me what the problem is and if it is in the code or the wiring (in the wiring diagram i couldn't find a 2 digit display but i used a 1 digit one as it has the same amount of pins so keep in mind that the wiring is for a 2 digit one).

[Thanks in advance.
[wiring diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXGUD.png)

Comment: I thought of making the delay for example like 10ms which makes the switching virtually invisible but i'm still wondering if maybe you can just display 2 different numbers at the same time

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an electrical question.

Comment: You need a driver/latch part to hold the first digit's value while you switch to the second digit, and vice versa.  This is an electrical/electronics question.  In a typical design you'd have one driver per 7-segment display, or you can get a dual driver that can drive two displays (or one two-digit display).

Comment: @TomServo Thank you for the answer can you recommend and drivers/latches to me as i'm pretty new also there is no electrical tag and where else am i meant to post the question

Comment: No need for a latch for only 2 digits in the display.  Millions of very functional alarm clocks were made without latches.

Comment: @noob69 There are too many to list here.  As another commenter noted, it is *possible* to drive two digits without latches, but you have to switch back and forth so each gets refreshed at least 50Hz.  His answer will work for you assuming you don't need to to anything else with the microcontroller, because `delay` is a blocking routine.  On the other hand, if you use drivers/latches, you can drive them without delays *at all* and can do other things in the other 99.999% of the time.

Comment: you don't turn off the digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to display 2 digits at the same time...  That won't work.  You must set the lines for each digit sequentially, using the common to select the digit you are controlling.

Your code is almost there.  All you need to add is some delay, and turning off all segments while you tinker with the output lines.

Example:

```
// ...

void six() 
{
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);
    digitalWrite(b, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, LOW);
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, LOW);
}

void nine() 
{
    digitalWrite(a, LOW);
    digitalWrite(b, LOW);
    digitalWrite(c, LOW);
    digitalWrite(d, LOW);
    digitalWrite(e, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(f, LOW);
    digitalWrite(g, LOW);
}

void showDigit(int digit)
{
    switch(digit)
    {
    case -1:  // all  off
        digitalWrite(digit1, HIGH);        
        digitalWrite(digit2, HIGH);
        break;
    case 0:  // digit 1 ON
        digitalWrite(digit1, LOW);        
        digitalWrite(digit2, HIGH);
        break;
    case 1: // digit 2 ON
        digitalWrite(digit1, HIGH);        
        digitalWrite(digit2, LOW);
        break;
    }
}

// ...

void loop()
{
    showDigit(-1);
    six();
    showDigit(0);
    delay(10);     // this delay is usually in the 10-30ms range
    showDigit(-1);
    nine();
    showDigit(1);
    delay(10);
}
```

Usually other processing will take place during the 'delay' time..  I suggest you look up on state machine algorithms so your Arduino project can seamlessly control multiple multi-segments LEDs and do other processing at the same time.  But that's a totally different subject.

The reduced the duty cycle wil dim the LEDs a bit, but that can be compensated by reducing the segment series resistors.

IMPORTANT: Make sure the digit1 and digit2 lines are not connected to each other, or you may fry your Arduino.  If you only have one display, you'll be able to see only one digit.

Comment: Thank you for this i will try it later when i have time :)